# Objective c quotes and variables

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, quotes

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
NSAppleScript *sendCharlieImput = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"terminal\" to do script " charlieImputSelf " in front window"];
[sendCharlieImput executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

The variable charlieImputSelf is going to be put into the terminal window as a command. BUT I need to put charlieImputSelf in between 2 qoutes (like above). This is obviously not the correct way. Can someone help?

Thanks!
Elijah

Answer (score 10):

To be successful, you'll need to embrace the documentation.  [Start here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).  Then go [read this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i).

Going down the path of having to ask a question on SO about every line of code is not going to lead to success.

To answer this question, you want `stringWithFormat:`:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"some random string \"with quotes\" and %@ word in the middle.", @"this"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSString`'s `+stringWithFormat:` method:

```
NSAppleScript *sendCharlieImput = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Terminal\" to do script %@ in front window", charlieImputSelf]];
```